# SQL Trigger update/Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I'm creating a table and setting up a trigger to insert/update field_3 using field_1 and 2. See my example below.

```
ID | Start_Date | End_Date | Period |
1    3/10/17      3/20/17      10
2    2/05/17      3/10/17       5
```

Trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_insert_Period]
  ON  [dbo].[MEDICAL_EXCUSE]
  for update
AS 
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @Start_Date Datetime
declare @End_Date  Datetime
declare @Period Float

set @Start_Date = ( select me_start_date from inserted)
set @End_Date = ( select ME_End_Date from inserted)
set @Period  = ( select Period  from inserted)

update MEDICAL_EXCUSE
set @Period  = DATEDIFF(day,@Start_Date , @End_Date)

END
```

it won't trigger just work if you execute Manually.

Any help Much Appreciated.

Comment: what is your ask

Comment: also please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text.

Comment: what's your problem with this ?

Comment: One problem that the OP is probably unaware of is that this will fail when updating multiple rows. Triggers works per statement, not per row.

Comment: NEVER, and I mean never under any circumstances, set the value of a field from inserted or deleted to a scalar variable. This will fail miserably when someone does a multi-record insert, update or delete. Even worse, it will not error, it will just use the data from only one of the records.  This is a guarantee of eventual data integrity problems.

Comment: @HLGEM - even worse, by writing it as 3 *separate* `select`s, they're not even guaranteed to be obtaining data from the *same* row for each variable set.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that trigger don't update the Field_3.

Comment: what's your recommendation. can i have an example?

Comment: I assume there's a typo in your sample data since `2017-02-05` - `2017-03-10` is more than 5 days.

Comment: @Messi, I have over 30 years of database experience, I know where your problems are. Your trigger has multiple problems but frankly you need to learn that your technique is unacceptable at all times in every trigger not just this one. It is even worse when it actually runs because you don't know that it is broken. This is why people are jumping on you about this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues I see with your trigger. First you can never assume only one record is going to be updated ever. Enterprise databases (typically the only kind complex enough to need triggers) often are accessed outside the user application and a large insert might appear.

Next, you want to get the records from an insert, so it needs to be an insert trigger. And finally you are updating the value of the variable @period instead of the field Period in your table.

Try this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_insert_Period]
  ON  [dbo].[MEDICAL_EXCUSE]
  for insert
AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE ME
SET Period  = DATEDIFF(day,i.Start_Date , i.End_Date)
FROM MEDICAL_EXCUSE ME
JOIN Inserted i on i.id = me.id

END
```

You might also want this to work for updates as well, so then make it:

```
FOR Insert, update
```

Comment: Always test insert/update triggers with single record inserts, updates and multiple record inserts and updates.

Comment: Ok. I used your script and tested it. and when i use the same record to another multiple rows it updates the other row of this record to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a trigger.  Just use a computed column.  I think this is what you want:

```
alter table KOPS_MEDICAL_EXCUSE
    add period as (DATEDIFF(day, me_start_date, me_end_date));
```

Note that `datediff()` returns an integer, so there is no reason to declare anything as a `float`.

With a computed field, the value is usually calculated when you query the table.  You can materialize the value if you want using the `PERSISTED` keyword.

Comment: the reason i'm using trigger and float is because of the application restrictions.

Comment: @Messi - even if you need it to be `float`, that can be accomplished with a `cast` or `convert` here. I'd also strongly recommend a computed column - it'll save headaches.

Comment: I agree this is a first choice, provided the trigger information though in my answer since it seems he may not be allowed to do this. Also so the OP coudl understand the problems his trigger has.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Much appreciate.

Comment: @Messi . . . What kind of application restrictions.  If you can add a trigger, you should be able to add a computed column.  Computed columns are easier to maintain.  And a persisted computed column only does the calculation once.